# Basic doubt about stochastic integrals over general local martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider $M = (M_t)$ is a continuous square integrable **local** martingale and $$ \mathbb H ^2(M):= \left \{ \psi =(\psi_t)\  \text{is a real previsible process s.t.,} \forall t\geq 0, \ \mathbb E\left \{ \int _0 ^t  \psi _s ~d \langle M \rangle _s \right \}< + \infty \ \text {a.e.}  \right\}. $$
 If $ \phi =(\phi_t)   \in \mathbb H ^2(M)$ can we conclude that $I_t =\left(\int _0 ^ t \phi_s dM_s\right) $ is a martingale ?

My doubt comes from [this problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404116/proving-that-t-t-s-t-left-x-right-frac-n-12-int-0-t-frac-1) also asked here.

Thank's in advance for your enlightenments.

Comment: $1 \in \mathbb{H}^2(M)$.  You need to localize to get a martingale.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian: Yes of course ... How could I haven't think. All the localizing problem comes from $M $, not from $\phi$. Now, I see it clear than before. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian : Could you also take a look at the question referred in the text, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, no you cannot conclude that $I_t$ is a martingale solely from the fact that the integral is well defined, since $1 \in \mathbb{H}^2(M)$.

The result you want to complete your answer to the other question uses the following [characterization of martingales](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/StoCal/sc3.pdf) (Prop 2.9): A local martingale $X_t$ is a true martingale if and only if the collection $\chi_t = \{ T : T \mbox{ is a stopping time and }T \leq t \}$ is uniformly integrable.  A consequence of this is that if your local martingale is dominated by an integrable random variable, then it is a martingale.  For the local martingale in that problem, $1$ is a dominating function.